# Python time.clock() result not precise and way off

Tags: python, time, sleep, clock

I have the following script with which I measure real elapsed time forseveral sleep functions. I use either time.sleep() to pause the program or psychopy.core.wait() which is said to be more precise and use the high resolution timer. I'm testing the latter explicitly because the wait() function appears to cause some trouble (e.g. pauses the program shorter than it should).

```
from psychopy import core
import time
import scipy
import sys

times1 = []
times2 = []
times3 = []
times4 = []
testtime = 40   # Time to wait (40 ms)
n = 200         # Iterations
print "Starting timing test with", testtime, "ms as reference; running", n, "times."

for i in range(n):
    t1 = time.time()
    time.sleep(testtime/1000.0)
    measurement = (time.time()-t1)*1000
    times1.append(measurement)

    time.clock() 
    time.sleep(testtime/1000.0)      
    measurement = time.clock()
    times2.append(measurement) 

    t1 = time.time()
    core.wait(testtime/1000.0)
    measurement = (time.time()-t1)*1000
    times3.append(measurement)

    t1 = time.clock()  
    core.wait(testtime/1000.0)     
    measurement = time.clock()
    times4.append(measurement)

    if i%60==0:
        sys.stdout.write(".")

print
print "Low precision with time.sleep()"
print "Average is", scipy.mean(times1)
print "StdDev is", scipy.std(times1)

print
print "High precision with time.sleep()"
print "Average is", scipy.mean(times2)
print "StdDev is", scipy.std(times2)

print
print "Low precision with PsychoPy core.wait()"
print "Average is", scipy.mean(times3)
print "StdDev is", scipy.std(times3)

print
print "High precision with PsychoPy core.wait()"
print "Average is", scipy.mean(times4)
print "StdDev is", scipy.std(times4)
```

The output I get however is:

```
Starting timing test with 40 ms as reference; running 200 times.
....
Low precision with time.sleep()
Average is 39.0950024128
StdDev is 7.77598671811

High precision with time.sleep()
Average is 16.2315164609
StdDev is 9.24644085289

Low precision with PsychoPy core.wait()
Average is 40.830000639
StdDev is 21.7002567107

High precision with PsychoPy core.wait()
Average is 16.3130358691
StdDev is 9.24395572035
```

The time returned by time.clock() is way too low! And this happens consistenly across several systems we have here.

Is there anyone who has an idea what is going on here and what might cause this?

Comment: In python3.3+ you can use `time.perf_counter` to have access to high-resolution timers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the same as you are doing for `time.time()` and save the clock value before you do your sleep and subtract it to get your measurement. As you have it all your clock values are just measuring time since the process started.

Comment: Thanks, I though time.clock() returned the time since the last call to it and then reset its internal timer to 0.